# Is it possible that QFile::size() and QFile::readAll().size() differ for certain special files?

Tags: c++, qt, buffer-overflow, qfile, qbytearray

Seeing a weird crash due to read access violation. Here is the minimal code:

```
struct MyFile : QFile
{
  ...
  string read ()
  {
    QByteArray content;
    if(<something>)
      content = QFile::readAll();
    ...
    string buffer(QFile::size(), 0);
    if(content.isEmpty())
    {
      QFile::seek(offset);
      QFile::read(&buffer[0], buffer.size());
    }
    else
      ::memcpy(&buffer[0], content.data(), buffer.size());
      //                   ^^^^ 40034      ^^^^ 42690
    return buffer;
   }
}
```

Here it's trying to read a .png file. Somehow the `QFile::size()` returns `42690`, while the `QFile::readAll()` which is stored in `content` has a size of `40034`.

Unfortunately the filename is not handy to verify the actual size. Writing test code for text or png files, it always gives proper results.

How is that possible?
Below is a debug frame for reference:

[image]

Comment: I'll bet that for a text file on Windows, the sizes would be different. Remember that newline on Windows is *two* characters (two bytes), but will be read as one character.

Comment: As for the problem with the current code, how do you open the file? In binary or in text mode? And why do you inherit from `QFile`? For normal file-handling that doesn't really make much sense.

Comment: Please show a [mre]

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude, it's a many years old code and has never showed any problem. Apart from above, it has several extension over `QFile` to justify the inheritance. I am opening the file in Read-only mode of Qt. The unknown png file does have "\r\n" in it. In any case shouldn't `QFile::size()` & `QFile::readAll().size()` match??

Comment: @AlanBirtles, i myself tried to reproduce it minimally as mentioned in the post. But it doesn't. Above code is the part of what it look likes around the debug frames.

Comment: The documentation for the [`QIODeviceBase::Text`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qiodevicebase.html#OpenModeFlag-enum) mode flag states `"When reading, the end-of-line terminators are translated to '\n'. When writing, the end-of-line terminators are translated to the local encoding, for example '\r\n' for Win32"`.  So if the file is opened with the `QIODeviceBase::Text` flag set then the behaviour you're seeing is probably what I'd expect.

Comment: One more thing to note is that `QFile::readAll` will return less bytes in case the current file offset is non-zero.

Comment: @G.M., The platform is Windows, but file is opened with `QIODeviceBase::ReadOnly` flag. Will that interpret to `QIODeviceBase::Text` mode somehow? However your point is also valid and I would welcome to write it in form of an answer.

Comment: QFile::size() & QFile::readAll().size()  doesnot  match??  pls show a minimal reproducible example

Answer (score 0):

You code does not take the current file's seek position into account. Thus, in case there were some read operations already, it will crash, because `QFile::readAll` will return only a part of the file (from the current seek position till the end of file).

The other possibility is the use of `QIODeviceBase::Text` as mentioned in comments, but you're not using it, so it's not the case.

Comment: I am making sure that the file is `seek()`ed from 0th position. Since that code was not appearing in the aforementioned method, i didn't mention it. Files are opened in `ReadOnly`.

Comment: You are not making sure. I do not see the appropriate code in the code sample you provided. First, just add this code to make sure it's not the case (i.e. call `seek(0)` at the beginning of the method).